# v-on:click not working - dynamically added html element

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to get all images for a category using Vue

```
 <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-2 p-2">
  <a v-on:click="onCategoryManageImageClick($event)"  data-target="#location- 
  category-images">
 </span>
  </a>
 </div>
```

So the event onCategoryManageImageClick ($event) does not work, if I am adding a html block and then click on get image button.

this is index.js

```
      methods:{
        onImagesTabClick(){
        this.$root.$emit('activated-tab:location-images');
    },
    onCategoriesTabClick(){
        window.j1App.eventBus.$emit("j1-location-image-list:shown");
    },
    onCategoryManageImageClick: function(event) {console.log('working event..');
        event.preventDefault();
        window.j1App.eventBus.$emit("j1-location-category-image- 
 list:shown",event.currentTarget.id);
    }
}
```

So basically it need to to work like we do in jQuery

```
$(document).on('click',function{
   })
```

So it works either page load or if adding any new html element on DOM. same I want in Vue.

Comment: How do you add the HTML block? It does not show it the vue template, which would be the obvious way to do it.

Comment: I am adding html block using twig template, and then that block has the v-on:clcik atatched

Comment: <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-2 p-2">
  <a v-on:click="onCategoryManageImageClick($event)"  data-target="#location- 
  category-images">
  </a>
 </div>

this is the html block get added once user add more button

Answer (score 1):

You cannot alter the Vue template outside of Vue. That won't work. Vue compiles the template once when starting up and adds the event listeners to the rendered elements. If you add elements afterwards, Vue will not know about them.

The correct way of doing this would be to add those new elements in Vue.

```
<div 
  class="col-md-12 col-sm-2 p-2"
  v-for="item in items" 
  :key="item.id"
>
  <a 
     v-on:click="onCategoryManageImageClick($event, item)"  
     data-target="#location-category-images"
  >
  </a>
</div>
```

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html for documentation. In this case you need the `items` array variable in `data` and add more array elements to it, if you need more links.

Comment: But I am using vue  with twig templates, So I wonder how its works on page laod?

Answer (score 0):

Try raplacing your `a` tag with `p`

```
 <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-2 p-2">
  <p v-on:click="onCategoryManageImageClick"  data-target="#location- 
  category-images">
  </p>
 </div>
```

Comment: OK let me try that

Comment: ReferenceError: item is not defined

Comment: Hey, sorry that I got lost in stuff. Just use `p` tag and event like this `v-on:click="onCategoryManageImageClick"`. It will work for sure.

Comment: and I  need id of current clicked button so used onCategoryManageImageClick($event)

if you say to sue it just onCategoryManageImageClick then how can I get current clicked button ID ?

Comment: You can access the event inside method without passing it as `function($event){}`. Here is a pen that i created for reference. https://codepen.io/lambrohan/pen/oNxzRaN

Comment: ok its fine but the main issue is, v-on:cilck is not working on html element which is being added by jquery

Comment: did you understood the issue?